# Are there badges that haven't been awarded yet?

Tags: support, badges

I am asking if there are badges that haven't been awarded yet to any user.

More specifically:

1. Is there a way to see statistics about a selected badge (like number of users that it has been awarded to)?
2. How can I sort and group badges according to some characteristics (like number of users who have it)?

Comment: Something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254564/view-all-network-badges-in-a-single-place/254596#254596)?

Comment: and you can see that per [badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/altruist). Can you explain what you exactly need?

Comment: Yes, that link is very useful. But How can i sort and group badges according to some characteristics? (Also I want to know if there are badges that haven't been awarded yet by any user). @rene

Comment: any user, per site or network wide?

Comment: @MChaker is this not awarded on a specific site, or *any* site, network wide?

Comment: Per site if it is possible.

Comment: If you go to a site's badge page [Stack Overflow's, for example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) it says "n awarded" next to each badge. Search for one's that are blank. Do this for all sites.

Comment: I have thought about that but there is a lot of badges per site and i think it is hard to do it for all sites manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Stack Overflow as an example:

> Are there badges that haven't been awarded yet?

[<s>Nope</s> Yup.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) (Precognitive, Constable, and inevitably a bunch of tag badges not shown there if you want to count those.)

> Is there a way to see statistics about a selected badge (like number of users that it has been awarded to)?

[Yup.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

> How can I sort and group badges according to some characteristics (like number of users who have it)?

I would use [SEDE queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/315536) for this, you can gather all sorts of useful information there. There are also ways to query [all sites at once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254596/230261) (thanks rene). Note that this information is not quite up-to-date, it is updated weekly.

> I have thought about that but there is a lot of badges per site and i think it is hard to do it for all sites manually.

If you'd like to automate this, you can use [the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges#order=desc&sort=rank&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true). The `/badges` command contains a count for each badge, delivered in a form that can be used by an automated script to run through a list of sites if you'd like to do a bulk query.

For other sites, the same methods are available. `http://site/help/badges` will get you to the badges summary, the site can be selected in SEDE, and the API is available on all sites. Newer sites are more likely to have badges that nobody has earned yet, for example, [Health.SE has quite a few](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/badges) (missing user count next badge means none have been awarded).

Comment: I hit your "nope" link. Looks like the gold [**`[constable]`**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3108/constable) badge has never been awarded.

Comment: @DanBron Uh... I was just uh... testing you all. No *Precognitive* holders either.

Comment: Yeah, I think *precognitive* is a bit of an inside joke badge for the team: it can't, even in theory, be awarded. +1 on your answer for the edit.

Comment: @DanBron On SO it can't, but on other sites that went through [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), it can. For example, there are [52 on Health](http://health.stackexchange.com/help/badges/66/precognitive) (but no further ones can be awarded after the site opens; it's a very exclusive badge).

Answer (score 3):

There will always be unclaimed tag badges... those for newly created tags.