# How to retrieve "badge type" in Data Explorer?

Tags: support, badges, stack-exchange, data-explorer

I'm trying to write a query ([Badge Order Received](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/445704/badge-order-received)) on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, within whose results I want to link to a user's awards of a given badge. On Stack Overflow, such a link may be constructed through the URL template:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/<badgeTypeId>?userid=<userId>`

For example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26?userid=805681

Is there a way of retrieving this `badgeTypeId` (or whatever it's called)?

Comment: You can't. I have a feature request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254605/can-we-have-a-working-route-if-we-use-the-id-from-the-badges-table) to get a possible fix.

Comment: You can look into the hack I created [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254564/view-all-network-badges-in-a-single-place/254596#254596)