# Is there any real order for badges on different Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, badges

So I was recently trying to look up how much a certain badge was awarded on different sites when I noticed, that the badge URLs work on indexes and not on names.

For example the URL to the Unsung Hero badge on Stack Overflow: https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero

And the URL to the Unsung Hero badge on Ask Different: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/unsung-hero

On Stack Overflow, it's 226, on Ask Different 35. With different sites, it's completely different numbers.

Is there any real order to those indexes or is it listed anywhere?

Comment: There is no order and there is no master list. I've noticed and asked about this in a different context: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254605/can-we-have-a-working-route-if-we-use-the-id-from-the-badges-table

Comment: Maybe related as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254564/view-all-network-badges-in-a-single-place/254596#254596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot provide order but I can provide a table where you are able to look the IDs up manually or programmatically. I just made a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369665/is-there-a-table-of-badge-ids-for-all-stack-exchange-sites/) post about it.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem here is that different sites have different badges when it comes to [tag badges](/help/badges/44/discussion). On larger sites, they have been earned more, so new badges like Unsung Hero had to have higher numbers.

The `Badges` table in SEDE does have an `Id` column but that's more like an identifier for the award to a particular user, i.e. it corresponds to [this page](/help/badges/10/scholar?userid=1022382). The [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges) doesn't provide an identifier either.

If you do need a list, I fear you have to scrape a couple of pages:

- the [list of badges](/help/badges)
- the [list of all bronze tag badges](/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze)
- the [list of all silver tag badges](/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver)
- the [list of all gold tag badges](/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold)

Fortunately, they aren't paginated, not even on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know the list of all badges but I'm a bit too lazy to write a program that searches the Badges for the right `innerText`, then gets the `href` and then returns that URL to me, but I guess that is what I have to do.